# Show and hide a div on corresponding dropdown value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a **DIV** with two dropdown(maindd and subdd) and an ADD button in a seperate **DIV**. If i click ADD button i am generating another div with similar two dropdown which have same value(like maindd and subdd). If i click ADD button again, Again i am generating a div with two dropdown(Name maindd  and subdd). Like that how many times i want, i can click the ADD button and add a DIV with two dropdowns.

The question is, if i change the first **DIV** first dropdown (maindd)value, i need to show the **corresponding** dropdown(subdd) which is present in the same div not on the other **DIV**. Similarly for second DIV dropdown change, i need to show its corresponding second DIV second dropdown.

Note: By default all the second dropdown(subdd) is set to "*display:none;*" through CSS. I am using JQUERY.

Code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="records">
        <select class="recordnumber" name="maindd">
            <option value="first">first</option>
            <option value="second">second</option>
            <option value="other">other</option>
        </select>
        <select class="othertype" name="subdd">
            <option value="one">One</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div><input type="button>Add Row</button>
    <div class="records">
        <select class="recordnumber" name="maindd">
            <option value="first">first</option>
            <option value="second">second</option>
            <option value="other">other</option>
        </select>
        <select class="othertype" name="subdd">
            <option value="one">One</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div><input type="button>Add Row</button>
</div>
```

Tried This:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".recordnumber").on("change",function(){
        if ( this.value == 'other')
            {
                $(this).siblings(".othertype").show();
            }
        else
            {
                if(this.value != 'other')
                {
                    $(this).siblings(".othertype").hide();
                }
            }
    });
});
```

Is this the right approach to do it?

Comment: Saw a solution in Jquery for single dropdown value change, i am looking similar to that. But for multiple DIV with same dropdown values.

Comment: Using `this`, it should be easy....

Comment: @Ramesh yes we can do it by using this key word

Comment: @Ramesh Check my answer with demo may useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code may be useful that you want

```
$(".recordnumber").on("change",function(){
   $(".othertype").hide();
   $(this).siblings(".othertype").show();
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jr92srpo/1/)**

Comment: Tried with your suggestion and modified some part of it. Please let me know if this is right?

Answer (score 0):

check below code it may help for you

```js
$(".recordnumber").on("change",function(){
   $(this).siblings(".othertype").css("display", "block");
});
```

```css
.othertype{
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="records">
    <select class="recordnumber" name="maindd">
      <option value="first">first</option>
      <option value="second">second</option>
      <option value="other">other</option>
    </select>
    <select class="othertype" name="subdd">
      <option value="one">One</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" />
  </div>

  <div class="records">
    <select class="recordnumber" name="maindd">
      <option value="first">first</option>
      <option value="second">second</option>
      <option value="other">other</option>
    </select>
    <select class="othertype" name="subdd">
      <option value="one">One</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" />
  </div>
</div>
```